# Timer Function Issues

Tags: java

I am trying to make a mini matrix thing. All that it is supposed to do is shoot out either a 0 or a 1. The code for that is fine, but I am trying to get it to do a countdown at the beginning (3,2,1 - then begins). It is being called in a different file via `activate()`.

What isn't working is the timer. For some reason, it puts a 0 in front of the first 3:

```
03
2
1
```

As well as it doesn't activate the matrix function. Here is the code if anyone could help me out.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Matrix {

    public boolean matrix = true;
    static int interval;
    static Timer timer;

    public String activate() {
        String done = "";
        timer();
        return done;
    }

    private void matrix() {
        while(matrix) {
            System.out.print((int) (Math.random()+0.5));
            pressEnterToContinue();
        }
    }

    private void timer() {
        System.out.println("press ENTER to stop\n"+
                           "starting in");

        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;

        timer = new Timer();
        interval = 3;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(setInterval());
            }
        }, delay, period);
        matrix();
    }

    private static final int setInterval() {
        if (interval == 1) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        return interval--;
    }

     private void pressEnterToContinue() {
        try
        {
            System.in.read();
            matrix = false;
        }  
        catch(Exception e) {}  
    }
}
```

Just a FYI, the pressToContinue() is supposed to end the while loop by pressing ENTER.

Comment: just discovered that the 0 at the beginning is from the `matrix()`. Can't figure out why it has been activated there though.

Comment: The reason it gets activated is you don't wait for the timer to finish before calling matrix. Try using ScheduledExecutorService which will allow you to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this alternative...using `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Matrix {

 public boolean matrix = true;
 static int interval = 3;
 static Timer timer;
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

 public String activate() {
    String done = "";
    scheduleTimer();
    return done;
 }

 private void matrix() {
    while(matrix) {
        System.out.print((int) (Math.random()+0.5));
        pressEnterToContinue();
    }
 }

 public void scheduleTimer() {
    System.out.println("Starting in:");
    final Runnable timer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { System.out.println(setInterval()); }
    };

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        scheduler.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        matrix();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 private final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1) {
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
    return interval--;
  }

  private void pressEnterToContinue() {
    try
    {
        System.in.read();
        matrix = false;
    }  
    catch(Exception e) {}  
 }

  public static void main(String[] args){
     Matrix mat = new Matrix();
     mat.activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: The countdown works, now it is the stupid `pressEnterToContinue()` that is no longer working. LOL thank you for the help, should be able to figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

It is printed as a result of

```
System.out.print((int) (Math.random()+0.5));
```

Comment: The 0? I finally realized that...how would I get the `matrix()` to activate after the `timer()`?

Comment: yes, your 0 is printed by this line which prepends it before your timer setInterval()

Comment: Do you have any ideas of how to get it to come after? Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: have you considered using  ScheduledExecutorService instead of a Timer to schedule your periodic task. ScheduledExecutorService provides a shutdown() method that will execute any pending tasks. You can then call awaitTermination() to wait for shutdown() to finish.